# parsing values from a R list

Tags: r, list

I am using openxlsx to read data from multiple sheets of an excel file.  The following is the code:

```
tfile <- "/home/mycomp/Documents/latest.xlsx"
sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(tfile)
x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) openxlsx::read.xlsx(tfile, sheet = X,startRow=1, rows=1,cols=1,sep.names=" "))
```

Essentially, I am trying to read only the first line of the table. The first line is a merged cell.  The output of x looks like this:

```
> x
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] Total Secondages
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[3]]
[1] Product Groups (duration in secondages)
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I want to extract only the values in first element such as `Total Secondages` or `Product Groups`.  I tried using `unlist`, getting names of the list etc., but they all return `logical(0)`.

I want to extract these values as a character vector like `('Total Secondages', 'Product Groups')` etc.

Comment: how about `lapply(x, names)`?

Comment: Thanks...this worked....`unlist(lapply(x,names))`....I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have empty `data.frame`s, from which you can extract names.

```r
x <- list(NULL, data.frame("Total Secondages"=character(0), check.names=FALSE), data.frame("Product Groups"=character(0), check.names=FALSE))
x
# [[1]]
# NULL
# [[2]]
# [1] Total Secondages
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# [[3]]
# [1] Product Groups
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
unlist(lapply(x, names))
# [1] "Total Secondages" "Product Groups"
```